# How to reduce size of scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I tried this without luck.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyScrollBar}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Scroll bar template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Width="4" IsDirectionReversed="True" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb>
                <Thumb.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border x:Name="thumb" BorderThickness="0" Background="Gray" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="4"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Thumb.Style>
            </Thumb>
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The thumb has changed its width. But `ListBox` still leaves much more space for `ScrollBar` than I want. How can I decrease the space for `ScrollBar`?

[image: List box with a thin scroll bar to the right that has surrounding whitespace.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBox` uses a `ScrollViewer` internally in its control template. The default `ScrollViewer` template will use the scroll bar width defined in the `SystemParameters`. A simple way to adapt it is to override the key in the `ListBox` resources. Please note that there are different keys for the horizontal an vertical scroll bars. You might want to adapt both in the long run.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">4</system:Double>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyScrollBar}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Another way is to create a custom control template for the `ScrollViewer`. You can refer to the official styles and template [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for `ScrollViewer` to get an idea how to build this template. There is already an example, where you can adapt the scroll bar width.

```
<Style x:Key="MyScrollViewer"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Border Grid.Column="1"
                  BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />
          </Border>
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                     Width="4"/>
          <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can either make this style implicit by omitting the `x:Key`, so it will be applied to all `ScrollViewer`s in scope or you can create a custom `ListBox` control template, where you sepcify this template for the internal `ScrollViewer` in order to apply it only there.